# Orchard - How to send user Password with approve email

Tags: orchardcms

I must send User information when user is approved. I want to send password too. It is possible in Orchard ? For user email and name I use tokens, but password token is not available. I´m using Workflows for this...

My email format:

```
Your account was activated!<br />
<br />
Yor credentials:<br />
<br />
Email: {User.Email} <br />
Name: {User.Name} <br />
Password: {User.password} // no work :/
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Orchard doesn't know of any 'readable' password, the password is encrypted and only available as hashed, not in plain text. Besides that, the password isn't available as token, as you can see in Orchard.Tokens/Providers/UserTokens.cs. You can ofcourse create it for yourself, but the decrypted password isn't available

Comment: It also won't be very secure, because you will have to save the non-encrypted password somewhere, which could be potentially dangerous

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit of work if you don't want to compromise on security.

In Orchard 1.9 this should be safely possible to achieve with dynamic registration form and workflow, within that workflow context you should know the password's field value with `{FormSubmission.Field:Password}` so you can mail it with `Send email` activity.

But this will work only during registration and you have to notify user within that workflow, because plain password won't be saved anywhere and I'd advise against attempting that.

If you don't know how to create dynamic form or workflow you can read up on this article (there's also accompanying video at the end) http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/customizing-user-registration-and-login-with-dynamic-forms-and-workflows

Comment: Well, in fact there's no way to do that without compromising on security. Passwords should never, ever, be sent by email. Just don't do it.